# Confused with byte convertion to int

Tags: java, byte

How a `byte` value `b` when uses as `int` in the Integer.toBinaryString() have a binary value much more than `byte` type can contain? I thought `s1` should be in range [0, 11111111]. And how this bitwise operator (`b & 0B11111111`) changes the situation? It seems that it changes nothing because 0 & 1 = 0 and 1 & 1 = 1

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte b = (byte) -115;
        String s1 = Integer.toBinaryString(b);
        String s2 = Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0B11111111);
        System.out.println(s1); // 11111111111111111111111110001101
        System.out.println(s2); // 10001101
    }
}
```

Comment: For a byte, -115 dec is `10001101` bin. If you promote that byte to an int with the same value (which is what happens when you call `Integer.toBinaryString(b)`), -115 dec is `11111111111111111111111110001101` bin.

Comment: The high-order bit is the negative sign, and conversion extends this so that the result is the same number (-115 decimal) and still negative.

Comment: @NomadMaker so why -115 for `int` is `11111111111111111111111110001101` but not `10000000000000000000000010001101`? It seems that `int` have differed coding scheme than `byte`

Comment: @Denis_newbie You should look up twos-complement-representation for negative binary numbers. Int and byte have exactly the same coding scheme, except for the number of bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Integer.toBinaryString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) accepts an `int`, so you are actually converting the *int* `-115` to a binary string. As far as `Integer.toBinaryString` is concerned, the number you passed to it is always an `int`. The fact that you are *able* to pass a `byte` is because there is a [conversion from `byte` to `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) in an [invocation context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3). The `byte` is *converted* to `int` first, *then* passed to `Integer.toBinaryString`.

What's `-115` represented in 32 bit two's complement (representation of an `int`)? Well,

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 1101
```

That is the binary string you got.

---

The `& 0B11111111` here actually *does something*. The `&` operator causes the `byte` to undergo [numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), converting it to an `int`. Now we have `-115` as a 32-bit `int`, with all those extra leading 1s that we don't want. The bit mask then gets applied, resulting in the `int` 141 (1000 1101). We then convert *this* `int` to a binary string.

Answer (score 1):

For a byte, -115 dec is `10001101` bin. If you promote that byte to an int with the same value (which is what happens when you call `Integer.toBinaryString(b)`), -115 dec is `11111111111111111111111110001101` bin.

Whereas if you take your int -115 and `&` it with `0B11111111`, you get the last eight bits of `11111111111111111111111110001101`, which is `10001101` bin, 141 dec.

For a byte `10001101` bin is -115, because the largest bit is negative.
For an int `10001101` bin is 141 dec, and the largest bit isn't set because you're only using the smallest 8 bits of a 32 bit integer.